# Delay Execution Until User Has Submitted Input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way in Javascript to delay execution until a user has filled in data in an input form and pressed submit on a submit input button?

Specifically, my JS applet has some preset default layouts, but the user can also choose a custom configuration. If they choose "Create Custom", a form that was was previously hidden is set to appear. I need the execution to pause until they've submitted the data -- can this be done?

Comment: Add an event handler for form submit...?

Comment: yeah, but i specifically need to stop/delay execution until a form is submitted. are there event handlers for this? i understand other EHs that deal with clicks, mouseovers, changes, etc., but i'm unaware of any that fit my need, is there?

Comment: ah, i think is see how i can use EH's for this. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as far as I know there is no `sleep()` or `wait()` function in JavaScript. You will have to end your execution (i.e. a method returns) and freshly invoke a method after an event was triggered (i.e. the user submitted the data) or some timeout elapsed.

You can of course "stop" execution by going into an infite loop which does not return until a certain variable is set; and this variable is set after the user submitted data. But such infinite loops are no good practice

Answer (score 0):

Attach a form submit event handler.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.submit
- http://api.jquery.com/submit/